# Can I make a discord bot with discord.py without a prefix?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot in discord.py that doesn't react to commands, simply providing information. client = commands.Bot() Throws an error if I dont have command_prefix = '' in it. Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: Instead of just saying "Throws an error", It is better to provide the error in the question, so you can get the best support possible. But in this case, the error is easily reproducible and guessable. But keep that in mind for the near future

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating your bot like so:

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="")
```

That will set your command prefix to `""`, an empty string, so any messages sent will be parsed into a command by your bot.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass an empty string as your prefix, like so:

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='')
```

Then, you can also override the `on_message` event to not process commands:

```py
# This overrides the event to do nothing, but you can also put your own code in here.
@client.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `client = discord.Client()`, since the bot class adds the command functionality, which you don't want. This is the intended way, and you can still access the other functionality.

Comment: Doesn't using `Client` also remove the cog functionality?

Comment: Yeah but you only usually only need cogs for commands. @TheFungusAmongUs

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a script like that without using `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="")`:

```py
import discord
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    
async def on_ready(self):
    print(f'Logged in as {self.user} (ID: {self.user.id})')
    print('---')
    bot_test_channel = self.get_channel(944602051671887902)
    await bot_test_channel.send('Premier fichier initialisée 0.1')
```

And for commands:

```py
async def on_message(self, message):
    if not message.content.startswith(bot_prefix):
        return
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    print(f'Message: {message.content}')
    print('---')
    
    if message.content == f'{bot_prefix}version': 
        myEmbed = discord.Embed(
            title='Version en cours',
            description= f'La version est **{version}**',
            color=0xFD6C9E,
        )
        myEmbed.add_field(
            name='Code version',
            value =f'{version} v0.0.1',
            inline=False,
        )
        myEmbed.add_field(
            name='Date prévue de prochaine version',
            value ='6 mars 2022',
            inline=False,
        )
        myEmbed.set_footer(text=self.user)
        await message.channel.send(embed=myEmbed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you want to make no prefix then you can add this func in your code

```
def get_prefix(client, message): 
    return ""

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

in this function it is returning None or "" a empty string which means there is no prefix